# PICARD_BRIDGE_CALLBACK variable javascript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

When javascript errors are occuring on a client of my website, the error will be sent to the server and will be saved into a logfile.

Going through the file there are some cryptic errors, which I can't figure out at all:

```
Line: 1 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ____PICARD_BRIDGE_ASYNC_CALLBACK____08597307465970516
```

Sometimes (but much more rarely) I also got:

```
Line: 1 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ____PICARD_BRIDGE_EVENT_CALLBACK____08992069498635828
```

I am using: Jquery Mobile 1.4.5, Jquery 2.1.4 and the nativedroid 1 library.
On the server I am using Play Framework 2.4

Anybody got an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this "cryptic" name `PICARD_BRIDGE_ASYNC_CALLBACK` as a default name for callback functions in `kik.js`. You can see examples of this file [here](https://github.com/mitchellvanderhoeff/kikcah/blob/91d6290008dcc4a40ceb97493a4dd5223a13332a/app/vendor/kik.js) and [here](https://github.com/chepchepcirkus/game/blob/0d8020ed09a45e5cf4dc0f4f73cd65ef07530d28/CLIENT/tank_webGL/tanx/kik.js)

This javascript file is probably used in your client. It's used with Kid Cards.

Comment: Thanks I indeed use the kik library on my app.